# Remove specific line in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a YouTube video thumbnail with this

```
echo '<a href="' . $video_url . '"><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/' . $video_id = $video_id[1]. '/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="' . $video_title . '" /></a>';
```

but that returns:

```
http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/zbZu8cOTh_4&feature=youtube_gdata_player/maxresdefault.jpg
```

but I want it to return:

```
http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/zbZu8cOTh_4/maxresdefault.jpg
```

So I have to find a way to remove

```
"&feature=youtube_gdata_player"
```

from the url.

How do I do that? 
I've tried

```
$video_id = str_replace('&feature=youtube_gdata_player', '', $video_id)
```

but I can't get that to work.
(I'm new to PHP, so I probably made some stupid error.)

Comment: the problem is not from  the PHP side, but how you get the thumbnails with the YouTube API

Comment: `str_replace()` should work. Show the actual code you tried, it looks like you're getting confused between `$video_id` and `$video_id[1]`.

Comment: Doing the variable assignment in the middle of the `echo` line like that is probably what's tripping you up.

Comment: If you're using youtube API then you can just read it directly from `media$thumbnail` and get the full URL from `hqdefault` or `sddefault` which are the biggest size.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regex :

```
$string = "zbZu8cOTh_4&feature=youtube_gdata_player";
$pattern = '/(&[\w\W]+$)/i';
$replacement = '';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

or with strpos :

```
$string = "zbZu8cOTh_4&feature=youtube_gdata_player";
$p = strrpos($string, "&");
substr($string,0, $p);
```